# Multiple entries showing on a report

Tags: civireport

For some reason, a particular report shows multiple entries for some users. These users have ACLs applied, so I wonder if that's causing the problem?

When I masquerade as a user with limited access, I don't see a problem, but I've just had this screenshot (photo!) sent to me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could all be the same report -> but users could have selected different columns, filters and group by settings;

Comment: @karing-semper-it thanks for the suggestion, it ould be something like that, but it's a contact report (not an activity or relationship report) so I can't understand how there would be more than row per contact. I don't think I could replicate it if I tried to, using the sort/group and columns/filter options.

Comment: if it is definitely a Contact based report, then i would add that to your original question

Comment: or are they duplicates? or is it an outcome from using Multiple Record Custom Fields?